# Installing Node.js ./configure make sudo make install

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I am currently trying to download node.js. I have downloaded everything and am now at the part where I enter the console commands.

What I am entering:

```
cd node
./configure
make
```

after entering `./configure`, i get this error

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer director /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`
```

I'm not sure what this means. After entering `make`, i then get this repeated in a infinite loop in the console

http://pastebin.com/YrDs2Afw

Comment: "tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode" — So install XCode…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general it's a good rule of thumb to provide a bit information about what you already tried and on what system you are - especially when you are having issues with installing something.

I'll just assume, that you're working on a Mac.

I would recommend to download and install XCode as Quentin already recommended.
You can find it in the AppStore.

Once that done, make sure to install the "Command Line Tools" within XCode.

Now you have several options: 
- Install Homebrew and install NodeJS from there (google Homebrew if you don't know what it is)
- Download and execute the Node v0.10.26.pkg (current version as of writing this), which will take care of the installation for you.

Hope this helps